# What am I missing from this SQL

Tags: sql

What am I missing in the below:

```
WHERE sls.SalesStatus IN (1,2,3)  
AND hdr.DeliveryDate <> (CASE ISNULL(sls.SalesStatus,'1')
```

I am getting this error message:
Incorrect syntax near ')'

Thank you!

Comment: Your CASE syntax is way off. No END for example.

Comment: I guess you wanted to replace a `(CASE WHEN sls.SalesStatus IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE sls.SalesStatus END)` with a simple `ISNULL(sls.SalesStatus,'1')` and forgot to remove the `(CASE `?

Comment: Ahh, let me try that.  I think you might be right.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.  I removed Case and I am good now. Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense.  You could mean this:

```
WHERE sls.SalesStatus IN (1, 2, 3) AND  
      hdr.DeliveryDate <> COALESCE(sls.SalesStatus, '1')
```

However, a column named `DeliveryDate` is an unlikely candidate for a comparison to either a string or the string value `'1'`.

It is possible that you mean something like:

```
WHERE sls.SalesStatus IN (1, 2, 3) AND
      hdr.DeliveryDate <> (CASE ISNULL(sls.SalesStatus,'1') WHEN '1' THEN ? ELSE ? END)
```

This is just speculation, but you would need to complete the logic.